# visual studio 2017 does not allow to compile multiple projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to rebuild some projects in Solution Explorer window.

I'm choosing some projects by shift button -> RMB -> Rebuild Selection but nothing done.

The output in Output window:

======== Rebuild All: 0 successed, 0 failed, 0 skipped =================

When I try to rebuild this projects one by one (Select project -> RMB -> rebuild), its work.

Any solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just click on the solution and rebuild all projects?

Comment: I have 113 projects in solution and its not working (problems with dependencies)

Comment: Hmmm, Its weird I just checked in my visual studio, CTRL highlight the project you want right-click rebuill, and it worked.

Comment: Its worked well in previous versions of visual studio (same solution)

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled vs2017 and it worked well...